# Como habilitar o des habilitar campos de un formulario con un switch

Tags: reactjs

Buen día! Tengo un formulario con el cual se realiza el guardado de datos y tambien la busqueda. Lo que quiero hacer es que con un switch habilite o des habilite algunos campos ya que para la busqueda no ocupo todos los campos que hay en el formulario.
El formulario es de la siguiente manera.

```
<div>
               <div className='card-panel'>
               <div className="switch">
                    <label>
                    Save commet
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <span className="lever"></span>
                    Search commet
                    </label>
                </div>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col s12 m12 l12'>
                            <div className= 'row'>
                                <div className='input-field col s12 m3 l3'>
                                    <input value={this.state.booking_no} ref={ref => this.refInputNo = ref} name="booking_no" type="number" className='validate' onChange={this.onInputChangeNo.bind(this)}/>
                                    <label htmlFor="booking_no" >Numero de comentario</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
                                    <input value={this.state.idclv_propiedad} ref={ref => this.refInputProp = ref} name="idclv_propiedad" type="number" className='validate' onChange={this.onInputChangeProp.bind(this)}/>
                                    <label htmlFor="idclv_propiedad" >Hotel</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
                                    <input value={this.state.reservacion} ref={ref => this.refInputRes = ref} name="reservacion" type="number" className='validate' onChange={this.onInputChangeReserva.bind(this)}/>
                                    <label htmlFor="reservacion" >Reservación</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className='col s12 m4 l4'>
                                    <label htmlFor='idbooking_comments_catalog'>Tipo de comentario</label> 
                                        <select name='idbooking_comments_catalog' value={this.state.idbooking_comments_catalog} className='browser-default' onChange={this.onInputChangeCommentCat.bind(this)}>
                                            { this.state.getTipoComment.map((tipocom)=>
                                                <option key={tipocom.value} value={tipocom.value}>{tipocom.text}</option>)
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className=" col s12 m4 l4">
                                    <label htmlFor="estado" >Estado</label>
                                    <select value={this.state.estado} name="estado" className='browser-default' onChange={this.onInputChangeEstate.bind(this)}>
                                    <option value='' disabled>Choose your option</option>
                                    <option value='1'>Active</option>
                                    <option value='0'>Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className='input-field col s12 m10 l10'>
                                <i className='material-icons prefix'>speaker_notes</i>
                                    <textarea value={this.state.booking_no_comment} id="textarea2" name="booking_no_comment" type="text" className='materialize-textarea' data-length="500" onChange={this.onInputChangecomment.bind(this)}/>
                                    <label htmlFor="textarea2">Comentario</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col s12 m10 l10'>
                            <button onClick={this.saveData.bind(this)} type='submit' className="btn waves-effect waves-light" data-position="bottom" ><i className="material-icons right">save</i>Save</button>
                            <button onClick={this.getSearchComment.bind(this)} type='submit' className="btn waves-effect waves-light right" data-position="bottom" ><i className="material-icons right">search</i>Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Espero me haya expllicado bien, de cualquier forma quedo atento.

Comment: Cómo determinas que un campo debe estar o no habilitado? Y requieres quitarlo o solo deshabilitarlo?

Comment: Solo cuado el switch este en "Save comment" estaran habilitados todos los campos y cuando este en "Search comment" solo los primeros 3 campos estaran habilidatos. lo que me gustaría hacer es que se deshabiliten.